# How can I send keyboard input into a GNU screen session without attaching to it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, gnu-screen

I need to send keyboard input to a GNU `screen` session **without attaching to it**.

I have tested this example but it does not work:

```
screen -S ffa3 -X "say SERVER REBOOT IN FEW MINUTES"
```

---

No I am also looking to use it for other commands too.

```
as: map_restart
    addadmin
    addop
    unban
    kickban...
```

I want to be able to type commands in the desired screen without ratacher me one.

in this form: *I told one screen to type **map_restart** or **others commands***

***R***eally thank you for the interest has increased my worries.

---

I use Screen with steamcmd for launch my server

With this command :

```
screen -dmS ffa ./run_server_x64.sh
```

And for type commands i use:

```
screen -r ffa
```

With that i can use admin panel

But i seek screen commands for type commands without use "screen -r ffa".

Comment: Please could you [edit] your question to explain a little more about this requirement. Why can't you attach to the screen session?

Comment: I edit my post for details

Answer (score 3):

Is this an XY problem?

```
shutdown -r +10 'Server reboot in a few minutes'
```

Or

```
echo 'Server reboot soon' | wall
```

---

Ah. You want a Steam RCON command line client. (Why didn't you say so?)

- http://steamcommunity.com/app/346110/discussions/0/530646715637849031
- http://python-valve.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rcon.html